# Filling empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

This is a simplified version of my code. I want to set B column cells values, but the function returns #value error. But if I delete `Range("B" & xdata.Row).Value = v` line, function works correctly. How do I set values to B column?

```
Function Calc(range_data As Range) As Double
        Dim v As Double

    For Each xdata In range_data
        If IsEmpty(Range("A" & xdata.Row)) = False Then   
                v = Range("A" & xdata.Row).Value * 2
                Range("B" & xdata.Row).Value = v
                Calc = Calc + v
```

Comment: You can't change the value of other cells in a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the values of other cells from within a user defined function.

For what you are trying to do, you should be using a `Subroutine`.

The code will work as expected then.

You may find the following an interesting, relevant read:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx